# --remote-schema option for rdiff-backup

Tags: backup, rdiff-backup

I'm running the following command:

```
rdiff-backup --remote-schema '%s' 'sudo /usr/bin/rdiff-backup --server \
    --restrict-read-only /'::/etc /var/backups/hosts/derp
```

It's backing up `/etc` from `localhost` and putting it in `/var/backups/hosts/derp` just fine. I have no idea how to get this to run and pull the files from another host.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the source and destination with `user@host:/folder` style. From the man page of `rdiff-backup`:

```
rdiff-backup      [options]      [[[user@]host1.foo]::source_directory]
[[[user@]host2.foo]::destination_directory]
```

And `--remote-schema` refers to the type of connection to the remote host -- ssh by default.